# How to change input file name before uploading

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to change the image that the user wants to upload, with my pattern Instead of original name.
I know . It's better change the file name on the server. but for some reasons I can't do this.

```
const [getImageFile, setImageFile] = useState([]);

const handleImageFile = e => {
    setImageFile([...getImageFile, e.target.files[0]])
};
```

thanks for your response.

Comment: If you are talking about an `<input type="file".../>` file upload, you can not interfere with the name of this field before uploading for security reasons. You should alter this at the server, but if you want to pass in a name, just add an additional text field for the new name.

Comment: @scunliffe Thank you for your response. I'll send the file name with the file to the server

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good practice nevertheless if you want to, you can do this

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [getImageFile, setImageFile] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(getImageFile);
    const file = new File(getImageFile, "mynewfile.jpeg");
    console.log(file);
  };

  const handleImageFile = (e) => {
    setImageFile([...getImageFile, e.target.files[0]]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={handleImageFile} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you check the logs you can see the change in the filename

Comment: can you elaborate why is it not considered the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Change with your input id name');
var image = element.files[0];
var blob = image.slice(0, image.size);
newFile = new File([blob], `Here you put the image name that you want`, { type: `${image.type}` });
```

Hope this helps!